# How to join table using a pool connection?

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to use pool to join two remote tables (`City` and `Country`) using below code:

```
pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)

src_pool(pool) %>% 
  tbl('City') %>% 
  left_join('Country', by=c('CountryCode'='Code'))
```

But this is the error I get when  run the code:

```
    Error: x and y don't share the same src. 
Set copy = TRUE to copy y into x's source (this may be time consuming).
    In addition: Warning message:
    In force(expr) : You have a leaked pooled object. Destroying it.
```

Below a working example of the same query using `dplyr`:

```
srccon <- src_mysql(
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  user  = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
tbl(srccon, 'City') %>% 
  left_join(tbl(srccon, 'Country'), by=c('CountryCode'='Code'))
```

And another example using `pool::dbGetQuery`

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM City LEFT JOIN Country ON (CountryCode=Code)"
dbGetQuery(pool, sql)
```

Comment: Looks more like a MySQL error message. Perhaps there is some way to see what string is getting passed to the underlying DB?

Comment: @42- I edited the question and the error message. I know I can use `dplyr::explain()` for printing mysql sintax, but in this case it just retrieves the same error message I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with pool, but the error message:

```
Error: x and y don't share the same src. 
Set copy = TRUE to copy y into x's source (this may be time consuming).
```

is due to the fact that one of your tables is being manipulated in-database (I'd guess `City`) and the other is in memory/not in the database ('Country'), but it could be the other way around. In this instance, `x` and `y` are your two tables, and the error message is just telling you they're not bothin the same place. By setting `copy = TRUE` the tibble in `y` will be (temporarily) copied into wherever `x` is stored (e.g. either to the database or into RAM) in order to perform the computation.

You could try either bringing both objects into memory using `dplyr::collect()` which will mean that the join happens in memory; or ensure that both are on your database (in which case the join will occur there instead).

i.e.

```
# Keep both in RAM
City <- tbl('City') %>% collect()
Country <- tbl('Country') %>% collect()

joined <- City %>% left_join(Country, by = c('CountryCode' = 'Code))
```

I would guess that the `Warning` about a `leaked pooled object` relates to the same issue (one table is in-memory, one is on the database).